# How can i close my Scene by clicking on button in javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to close scene(which is currently opened),
i want to do like Cancel or close button operation
written the statement 
x.show();
in another class
and want to close x means
x.close();
in another class

Comment: Send your stage to other controller class and write  `your_stage.close();`

Comment: Just do `button.getScene().getWindow().hide();` (where `button` is your button - you can use anything else that is displayed in the same scene).

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
private void closeScene(ActionEvent event){
    final Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
    final Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}
```